# how to insert string as datetime datatype of sql server in java?

Tags: java, sql-server

how to insert string as datetime datatype of sql server in java?

if the string as `"2017-10-05 09:25:55"`
i want to insert this `string` as `[date-time]` datatype of read_time column
 in SQL server

thanks in advance

Comment: Parse that String into a `java.sql.Date` then set the value using a `PreparedStatement.setDate(int, Date);` on your `PreparedStatement`. Of course this require a `PreparedStatement`. Note that `PreparedStatement.setObject` might work with a `java.util.Date` or `java.time.LocalDateTime` based on the JDBC used.

Comment: Use a prepared query with stongly-typed datetime parameter value.

Comment: can you post those 4 lines code

Comment: Have you checked the JavaDocs of JDBC? If you can indicate why existing functions do not solve your problem please update your question. http://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/

Comment: @Naveen nope because you didn't tried ... try yourself ... follow some tutorial if you need ... And for that, you need more than 4 lines.

Comment: i am trying from more than 3 hrs i did not get any clues

Comment: CAST('2017-10-05 09:25:55' AS DATETIME)  this function worked

Comment: @AxelH thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place the below statement in your `Insert` Query.

```
CAST('2017-10-05 09:25:55' AS DATETIME)
```

Comment: Even it this might work, this will be DBMS depend (the default format, the function itself). I suggest to parse the `String` yourself to prevent any problem.

Comment: @Shyam Vemula thanks a lot it worked

Comment: @Naveen Your Welcome

Answer (score 2):

1. Parse the `String` into a `java.util.Date` using a `SimpleDateFormater`
2. Create a `PreparedStatement`
3. Pass the date as a `java.sql.Date` (using the `java.sql.Date(long)` constructor) to the parameter of that statement using `PreparedStatement.setDate(int, java.sql.Date)`
4. Execute that statement
5. See the result.

For that, you will need a `Connection`, the JDBC (jar) for the DB and the correct `INSERT` query with parameter for the `PreparedStatement` like `INSERT INTO table (col_timestamp) VALUES(?)`.

Answer (score -1):

############## Try It

import java.sql.Date;

String string_date_var = "05-10-2017";

// Preparing statement for date insert

pStmt = connection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO table_name(date_col_name) values(?)");

// Setting the value of date

pStmt.setDate(1,Date.valueOf(string_date_var));

// Running the query

pStmt.executeUpdate();

```
        OR
```

import java.sql.Date;

String string_date_var = "05-10-2017";

// Here 'YYYYMMDD' is the date format used in database column

pStmt = connection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO table_name(date_col_name) values(To_Date(" +string_date_var+ ",'YYYYMMDD'");

// Running the query

pStmt.executeUpdate();

Hope it helps !